# Imageindex and stateindex in a treeview

Tags: delphi, treeview, wmi, delphi-xe2

I coded a function that gets the list of installed software on the computer using WMI

```
begin
  Result:='';
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('Select %s from %s',[WMIProperty, WMIClass]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;

  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
      if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value) then
      Result:=FWbemObject.Properties_.Item(WMIProperty).Value;
      ClientForm.TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Node, Format('%s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));
      FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
    end;

end;
```

The function get executed at FormCreate by the following code:

```
GETWMIstringSW('Win32_Product','Name');
```

The question I have is, How can I change the ImageIndex and StateIndex?  I want to add another line of code to the function to also get the Version, something like this

```
(Format('Version %s',[String(FWbemObject.Version)]));
```

But I'm stuck, can you guys please point me in the right direction?  Thank you so much.

Comment: user2296519: if an answer below is helpful/correct, please consider clicking the "check" mark to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AddChild](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNodes.AddChild) function returns an instance to the new node, so you need to save the node and then modify the properties.

```
Var
  LNode : TTreeNode;
begin
   ..
   LNode := ClientForm.TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Node, Format('%s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));
   LNode.StateIndex:=0;
   LNode.ImageIndex:=0;
   ..
   ..
end;
```

Comment: Great that worked, thank you so much.  Any idea how to make the Version be listed under the software name, I know I have to change the state index to 2 before adding another child but I don't know how.

Comment: @user2296519: That would be a different question, and should be posted as such. This one was about setting `ImageIndex` and `StateIndex`, and RRUZ has answered that one.